# Get first text and split using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to split the content by finding the first text from the column. Below are the text and result.

```
Input            Output
00Abc def        Abc def
0Abc hf001       Abc hf001
01738Hji hf      Hji hf
7HAJ he          HAJ he
HJSHJS gef       HJSHJS gef
```

Comment: Input 00Abc def
Output Abc def
Input 0Abc hf001
Output Abc hf001

Comment: This is pretty vague.  How about creating a spreadsheet with before and after and upload a screen shot?  For instance, the first part is relatively easy, just replace "0" with "", but I don't get what the results should be of 01738Hji...

Answer (score 0):

I stole this answer, so all credit to this question.

https://superuser.com/questions/846822/find-first-letter-in-a-string

That questions gives you the position of the first ASCII character, which you can then use with `MID`, to create the following, assuming your data starts in `A1`,

```
=MID(A1, MIN(INDEX(ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1)))+((CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))<65)+(CODE(MID(UPPER(A1),ROW(INDIRECT("1:"&LEN(A1))),1))>90))*1E+99,,)), LEN(A1))
```